# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: student (code 1): , while compiling:

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I don't know what is wrong here

```
package mytwistedidea.wordpress.com.testingdata;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Nishant on 22-02-2017.
 */

public class DatabaseHelper {

    static MyHelper helper;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        helper = new MyHelper(context);
    }

    public long insertStudent(int roll, String name, String attended){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MyHelper.ROLL,roll);
        contentValues.put(MyHelper.NAME,name);
        contentValues.put(MyHelper.ATTENDED,attended);

        Long id = sqLiteDatabase.insert(MyHelper.TABLE_NAME_STUDENT,null,contentValues);
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
        return id;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getStudent(Integer roll){

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<Integer> previousRoll = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String columns[] = {MyHelper.ROLL};

        String query = "SELECT * FROM "+MyHelper.TABLE_NAME_STUDENT+" WHERE roll='" + roll;

        Cursor  cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        arrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyHelper.ROLL)));
        arrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyHelper.NAME)));
        arrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyHelper.ATTENDED)));

        return arrayList;
        /*
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MyHelper.TABLE_NAME_STUDENT,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                previousRoll.add(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyHelper.ROLL))));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }if(previousRoll.size() == 0){
            previousRoll.add(0,0);
            return previousRoll;
        }
        return previousRoll;*/
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getAllStudent(){

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<String> previousStudent = new ArrayList<String>();
        String columns[] = {MyHelper.ROLL,MyHelper.NAME,MyHelper.ATTENDED};

        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MyHelper.TABLE_NAME_STUDENT,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                previousStudent.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyHelper.ROLL)));
                previousStudent.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyHelper.NAME)));
                previousStudent.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyHelper.ATTENDED)));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }if(previousStudent.size() == 0){
            previousStudent.add(0," ");
            return previousStudent;
        }
        return previousStudent;
    }


    public static ArrayList<Integer> getStudentRoll(){

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<Integer> previousRoll = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String columns[] = {MyHelper.ROLL};

        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MyHelper.TABLE_NAME_STUDENT,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                previousRoll.add(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyHelper.ROLL))));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }if(previousRoll.size() == 0){
            previousRoll.add(0);
            return previousRoll;
        }
        return previousRoll;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getStudentName(){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<String> previousName = new ArrayList<String>();
        String columns[] = {MyHelper.NAME};

        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MyHelper.TABLE_NAME_STUDENT,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                previousName.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyHelper.ROLL)));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }if(previousName.size() == 0){
            previousName.add(0," ");
            return previousName;
        }
        return previousName;

    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> getStudentAttendence(){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<Integer> previousAttendence = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String columns[] = {MyHelper.ATTENDED};

        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MyHelper.TABLE_NAME_STUDENT,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                previousAttendence.add(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyHelper.ATTENDED))));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }if(previousAttendence.size() == 0){
            previousAttendence.add(0,0);
            return previousAttendence;
        }
        return previousAttendence;

    }


    class MyHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mystudent.db";
        private static final String TABLE_NAME_STUDENT = "student";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        private static final String NAME = "name";
        private static final String ROLL = "roll";
        private static final String ATTENDED = "attended";

        private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE"+TABLE_NAME_STUDENT+
                "("+ROLL+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+
                NAME+" VARCHAR(255), "+
                ATTENDED+" INTEGER);";

        private static final String DROP_STUDENT = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME_STUDENT;

        private Context context;

        public MyHelper(Context context){
            super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            if(db != null){
                try{
                db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
                }
                catch (SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            try{
                db.execSQL(DROP_STUDENT);
                onCreate(db);
            }
            catch (SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            try{
                db.execSQL(DROP_STUDENT);
                onCreate(db);
            }
            catch (SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

      }
    }
```

I am new to databases.
I don't know which part is wrong so I posted the whole code.

Comment: please read these: [ask] & [mcve] & [help/on-topic]

Comment: okay thanks. Please see the code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in below line

> private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE
>   TABLE"+TABLE_NAME_STUDENT+
>                   "("+ROLL+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+
>                   NAME+" VARCHAR(255), "+
>                   ATTENDED+" INTEGER);";

it should be like

> private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE
>   "+TABLE_NAME_STUDENT+
>                   "("+ROLL+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+
>                   NAME+" VARCHAR(255), "+
>                   ATTENDED+" INTEGER);";

There should be a space between"CREATE TABLE" and TABLE_NAME_STUDENT

Comment: Not Working Still. Same error At Line " Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MyHelper.TABLE_NAME_STUDENT,columns,null,null,null,null,null); "

Comment: Try to uninstall the application and then run it again, I have tested the code Its working by just making one change.


*private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME_STUDENT+" ( "+ROLL+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+ NAME+" VARCHAR(255), "+ ATTENDED+" INTEGER);";*